# Capture separately if there is a comma, capture it as a whole if there is not RegEx

Tags: php, regex

Im not really used to regular expression I want to capture The *`Lastname, Firstname`* if there is a comma and capture it as a whole if *`Lastname Firstname`* is provided.

E.g. if the user enters:

**Name:** *`Lastname, Firstname`*
I want to capture just the *`Lastname`*, *`Firstname*`

**Name:** *`Lastname Firstname`*
also this. excluding the **Name:**

Here is my Regex (what i've tried till now): `(([a-zA-Z]*),? ([a-zA-Z]*))`

Btw, I am extracting the data in an Excel cell
that has:

- `Name: Lastname, Firstname`, or
- `Name: Lastname Firstname` format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this regex,

It is case-insensitive, captures Lastname and Firstname seperately if there's a comma between them,

And captures together if there's no comma

`([^,\r\n]+)`

Output:

[image]

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/4m8Fu5/1)

You can also try them without using any classes, like `[^,\r\n]+`

**Edit:** After some discussions in the comments, i've came up with an another Regex, which avoids reading `Name:` in the string

`((?(?<=Name:)| )[^,\r\n]+)`

Output:

[image: image2]

[**Second Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/0sMYOp/1)

tell me if its okay for you...

Comment: Sorry my question is incomplete. How about if there is a Name: Lastname, Firstname and I only want to capture the Lastname Firstname? it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @zteezy try it in the given regex101 demo link, and tell what is wrong in my regex, and pls edit the question and explain in detail what you want....

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ttIqas/1 when having a Name: at the beginning

Comment: @zteezy updated my answer, check it out!